# Perguntas marcadas como pendentes depois de terem sido respondidas

Tags: debate, perguntas

Olá, sou novo na comunidade e estou respondendo algumas questões para treinar meus conhecimentos em algumas linguagens e ajudar o pessoal.
Ando percebendo que depois de que eu respondo algumas questões elas são marcadas como `pendente` , gostaria de saber qual o critério que é utilizado para identificar uma questão como pendente, pois vejo que alguns usuários não compreendem a questão e pedem mais informações, mais detalhes. Porém com aquela quantidade de detalhes eu consegui entender a pergunta e respondi.
A partir deste contexto, eu devo responder perguntas que (para mim) não são bem detalhadas, mesmo entendendo o que está sendo perguntado?

Comment: Se não estão bem detalhadas, mas você ainda assim consegue compreender, você pode editar a pergunta e melhorar naquilo que está faltando. Assim fica melhor para todo mundo :D

Comment: Depende da questão. Você entendeu ou acha que entendeu? Será que quem escreveu entendeu? Normalmente falta informações porque quem escreveu ainda não entendeu o problema. E quem l~e pode achar que entendeu, mas não. E uma pergunta que 2 pessoas entenderam e várias outras, em geral experientes, não entenderam tem algo errado. Como será que outras pessoas que chegarão nesta pergunta vão entender? Se estiver confuso, se acertou por coincidência, se estiver confuso que nem dá para avaliar, não é uma boa pergunta. Resolve o problema da pessoa, mas não atende o critério básico do SOpt:

Comment: Atender outras pessoas. Não somos um fórum, somos um repositório de perguntas s respostas que podem ajudar várias pessoas. Claro que sempre é possível que quem participou do fechamento tenha errado. O ideal é responder perguntas de qualidade que sirvam para outras pessoas. E, se tiver disposição, ajudar o AP deixar a pergunta em melhores condições antes de responder, pode ser que nem seja o caso de perder tempo de responder, porque em muitos casos o detalhamento mostra que era outra coisa. Claro que também tem os casos de linha tênue.

Comment: Um exemplo de resposta que não ajudou de fato e muitas vezes seria convertido em comentário ou negativada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344149/101. E a https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344808/101 é o que chamamos de lista de compras. Indica umas coisas que podem ou não serem úteis, é só sugestão sem um muito critério, são só dicas, não uma resposta que dá para afirmar que é certa. Ela ajuda indicar que a pergunta não é boa, e poderia ser fechada por quase todos os motivos.

Comment: Cara, entendi. Obrigado por me mostrar esses pontos que eu não estava percebendo. Vou me atentar mais nesses detalhes e comentar antes de ir respondendo uma pergunta que não vai agregar em nada o objetivo do StackoverflowBr que é ser repositório de perguntas e respostas, temos que ser focados e objetivos e não sair dando dicas e sim respostas para perguntas bem formuladas para justamente agregam valor a esse repositório. Vlw.

Comment: @Maniero Permita-me uma sugestão: por que não pegar nos seus comentários e colocar numa resposta? Nem que seja só por copy e paste, o conteúdo ficará mais fácil de encontrar e de ler.

Comment: @ramaral é que não tenho certeza se isto responde mesmo, vamos ver o desenrolar, eu posso fazer isto sim.

Comment: Note que quando há alguma atividade em um post (por exemplo, uma resposta nova ou edição) ele vai para o topo da página principal. Neste momento a comunidade ou a moderação pode acabar identificando um post problemático que havia passado despercebido anteriormente entre outras postagens - o que pode criar esta relação entre responder um post, e este vir a ser fechado em seguida.